# Make a layout appear with animation after button click in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to implement a simple animation effect for login screen.

Here's the scenario,

**1:** Some text and a login button will be displayed by default.

**2:** After clicking the login button a new frame layout will appear from bottom to top. This layout will prompt user to enter their username and password.

I can make an animation which will overlay from one parent to another. In this scenario, I'm looking for an animation that will appear without leaving the activity.

Comment: Have you tried using [LayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html)?

Comment: If the animations are that simple, use Android's traditional translate animation and start it on any number of views to make them run in parallel.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First set `invisible` to your layout.
Set animation to slideUp and slideDown.

```
   final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
            Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);

            if(layout.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){

                layout.startAnimation(slideUp);
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

**slide_up.xml** (create in `res/anim` directory)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="500" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="500" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**Note:**
You should edit values in `slide_down.xml` and `slide_up.xml` until get favorable result.
for example:change `android:fromYDelta="500"` to `android:fromYDelta="700"`

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial, it explains some basic animations which you can customize for your need.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/